# How do I set 'current_user' even though a user is not logged in? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise for authentication, and when someone visits a specific URL (with specific params in the URL), I would like to set the 'current_user' to a specific value from the db.

How do I do that ?

Also, will I have to make sure all the validation requirements are satisfied ? E.g., my user model has:

```
validates_presence_of :username, :email
```

If I set the current_user, would I have to set both the :username & :email, or can I just do one or the other ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try

```
@user = User.where(:x => "y").first # Find the user depending on the params
sign_in(@user)
# do work
sign_out(@user)
```

I don't know if that's the best way to do it, but it will set `current_user`.

Comment: Well the thing is, what if the `@user` I want to set, is not from the model `User`, but from another model `Client` that is not managed by Devise ? i.e. I have two models. A `Users` model, and a `Clients` model. A `client` only has an email address. No username, no pw or anything. Whereas a `user` has the whole nine-yards. So I would like to override the `user` with the client if some params exist.

Comment: Devise sets `current_user` specific to a user. I guess if you have a user-client relationship defined, you could do something like `sign_in(@client.user)`, or your `@user = User.where(:email => @client.email)` would find the user and then sign it in.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you have a client with no cookies

Answer (score 8):

devise's `current_user` helper sets the instance variable @current_user, so doing this:

```
@current_user = User.first
```

will also set current_user to the selected user.

Comment: It actually set the current user but does not really sign him in as the authenticate before filter will not pass. So be careful when doing so.